# Add Date-Stamped Observations by Group in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
> head(dsidata3)
# A tibble: 6 x 28
  Date      `Day of week` Holiday Name   `Time entered` Work  Travel Exercise Sleep
  <chr>     <chr>         <chr>   <chr>  <time>         <chr> <chr>  <chr>    <dbl>
1 28/3/2018 Wednesday     NA      Dave   21:10          6.0   0.4    -         7.00
2 28/3/2018 Wednesday     NA      Mercu… 22:00          8.0   1.5    -         6.00
3 28/3/2018 Wednesday     NA      Mars   23:56          11.0  1.0    -         4.00
4 28/3/2018 Wednesday     NA      Venus  22:35          8.5   4.0    -         7.50
5 29/3/2018 Thursday      NA      Dave   22:00          -     -      -         6.00
6 29/3/2018 Thursday      NA      Mercu…    NA          8.5   0.8    1.0      10.0
```

For each date there are four observations (one for each $Name, 'Dave', 'Mars' etc)

I also have a seperate dataframe that looks like this

```
    > head(windspeeds)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Date       `km/h`
  <chr>       <int>
1 28/03/2018      2
2 29/03/2018      1
3 30/03/2018      0
4 31/03/2018      2
5 1/04/2018       1
6 2/04/2018       7
```

I would like to add my windspeed data to my first dataframe, however there are four of each date in that dataframe and only one observation per date in the windspeed dataframe.

I'm sure this has something to do with nesting and applying but I just cant figure it out, any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

As requested here is the dput of all observations for those variables:

```
> dput(dsidata3$Date)
c("28/3/2018", "28/3/2018", "28/3/2018", "28/3/2018", "29/3/2018", 
"29/3/2018", "29/3/2018", "29/3/2018", "30/3/2018", "30/3/2018", 
"30/3/2018", "30/3/2018", "31/3/2018", "31/3/2018", "31/3/2018", 
"31/3/2018", "1/4/2018", "1/4/2018", "1/4/2018", "1/4/2018", 
"2/4/2018", "2/4/2018", "2/4/2018", "2/4/2018", "3/4/2018", "3/4/2018", 
"3/4/2018", "3/4/2018", "4/4/2018", "4/4/2018", "4/4/2018", "4/4/2018", 
"5/4/2018", "5/4/2018", "5/4/2018", "5/4/2018", "6/4/2018", "6/4/2018", 
"6/4/2018", "6/4/2018", "7/4/2018", "7/4/2018", "7/4/2018", "7/4/2018", 
"8/4/2018", "8/4/2018", "8/4/2018", "8/4/2018", "9/4/2018", "9/4/2018", 
"9/4/2018", "9/4/2018", "10/4/2018", "10/4/2018", "10/4/2018", 
"10/4/2018", "11/4/2018", "11/4/2018", "11/4/2018", "11/4/2018", 
"12/4/2018", "12/4/2018", "12/4/2018", "12/4/2018", "13/4/2018", 
"13/4/2018", "13/4/2018", "13/4/2018", "14/4/2018", "14/4/2018", 
"14/4/2018", "14/4/2018", "15/4/2018", "15/4/2018", "15/4/2018", 
"15/4/2018", "16/4/2018", "16/4/2018", "16/4/2018", "16/4/2018", 
"17/4/2018", "17/4/2018", "17/4/2018", "17/4/2018", "18/4/2018", 
"18/4/2018", "18/4/2018", "18/4/2018", "19/4/2018", "19/4/2018", 
"19/4/2018", "19/4/2018", "20/4/2018", "20/4/2018", "20/4/2018", 
"20/4/2018", "21/4/2018", "21/4/2018", "21/4/2018", "21/4/2018", 
"22/4/2018", "22/4/2018", "22/4/2018", "22/4/2018", "23/4/2018", 
"23/4/2018", "23/4/2018", "23/4/2018", "24/4/2018", "24/4/2018", 
"24/4/2018", "24/4/2018", "25/4/2018", "25/4/2018", "25/4/2018", 
"25/4/2018", "26/4/2018", "26/4/2018", "26/4/2018", "26/4/2018", 
"27/4/2018", "27/4/2018", "27/4/2018", "27/4/2018", "28/4/2018", 
"28/4/2018", "28/4/2018", "28/4/2018", "29/4/2018", "29/4/2018", 
"29/4/2018", "29/4/2018", "30/4/2018", "30/4/2018", "30/4/2018", 
"30/4/2018", "1/5/2018", "1/5/2018", "1/5/2018", "1/5/2018", 
"2/5/2018", "2/5/2018", "2/5/2018", "2/5/2018", "3/5/2018", "3/5/2018", 
"3/5/2018", "3/5/2018", "4/5/2018", "4/5/2018", "4/5/2018", "4/5/2018", 
"5/5/2018", "5/5/2018", "5/5/2018", "5/5/2018", "6/5/2018", "6/5/2018", 
"6/5/2018", "6/5/2018", "7/5/2018", "7/5/2018", "7/5/2018", "7/5/2018", 
"8/5/2018", "8/5/2018", "8/5/2018", "8/5/2018")
```

And windspeed:

```
> dput(windspeeds)
structure(list(Date = c("28/03/2018", "29/03/2018", "30/03/2018", 
"31/03/2018", "1/04/2018", "2/04/2018", "3/04/2018", "4/04/2018", 
"5/04/2018", "6/04/2018", "7/04/2018", "8/04/2018", "9/04/2018", 
"10/04/2018", "11/04/2018", "12/04/2018", "13/04/2018", "14/04/2018", 
"15/04/2018", "16/04/2018", "17/04/2018", "18/04/2018", "19/04/2018", 
"20/04/2018", "21/04/2018", "22/04/2018", "23/04/2018", "24/04/2018", 
"25/04/2018", "26/04/2018", "27/04/2018", "28/04/2018", "29/04/2018", 
"30/04/2018", "1/05/2018", "2/05/2018", "3/05/2018", "4/05/2018", 
"5/05/2018", "6/05/2018", "7/05/2018", "8/05/2018"), `km/h` = c(2L, 
1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
3L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L)), .Names = c("Date", "km/h"
), row.names = c(NA, -42L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
```

Comment: what is your expected output? do you want the same windspeed against every row of that date?

Comment: Yes I want the windspeed for each date to appear on every row of the corresponding date

Comment: could you please use `dput()` on your input dataframes and provide that? it helps us recreate your scenario.

Comment: @Aramis7d done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering input as :

```
x1 <- 'A B
1 x
1 y
1 z
2 r
2 t
2 5'

x2 <- 'A D
1 x1
2 r1'

df1 <- read.table(text = x1, sep =" ", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- read.table(text = x2, sep =" ", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

you can just try `tidyverse` functions like:

```
df1 %>%
  left_join(df2)
```

which gives:

```
  A B  D
1 1 x x1
2 1 y x1
3 1 z x1
4 2 r r1
5 2 t r1
6 2 5 r1
```

Comment: Thank you again for your help, however this returns all NA values

Comment: most likely an issue due to different formats in your `Date` column... first shows `dd/m/yyyy` while second has `dd/mm/yyyy`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function `rep` with argument `each=4` to repeat each entry of windspeeds 4 times and then add it to your dataframe.

```
temp <- as.array(windspeeds["km/h"])
dsidata3["ws"]<- rep(temp, each = 4)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input!

Unfortunately i'm not getting the result i'm after.

> dsidata3["ws"]<- rep(windspeeds["km/h"], each = 4)
Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "ws", value = list(`km/h` = c(2L, 1L,  :
  provided 4 variables to replace 1 variables
> head(dsidata3$ws)
[1] 2 1 0 2 1 7

Comment: The function rep seems to have no effect on tibble columns. However, by converting "windspeeds["km/h"] to array first, it should work.